# Create datalab instance with Preemptible GPU?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

How to create datalab instance with Preemptible GPU?

I tried:

```
datalab beta create-gpu super --accelerator-type nvidia-tesla-v100 --accelerator-count 2
```

And it seems, there is no option to pick preemptible gpu.

[As well I see no option in instance settings:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye9tA.jpg)

Comment: And it failed? Your question does not really give much informations on your case.
Please take a look at [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: add error messages and some details please

Comment: Apologies, updated .

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are looking forward to a cost optimization by having the instance shutdown at a certain moment, correct me if I am wrong.

I recommend to use [Cloud Datalab VM Auto Shutdown](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/concepts/auto-shutdown). You have the flexibility to set a timer that is reset if:
- scrolling in a notebook window
- using the tree-list window, including when the tree list auto-refreshes (e.g., when returning to the window)
- running a command in a Cloud Datalab terminal tab

Answer (score 0):

There's a [feature request](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1494) for preemptible instance support.